# Two group cohomology are isomorphic to each other if they have the same coefficient.

Tags: homology-cohomology, group-cohomology, equivariant-maps

Suppose $M$ and $N$ are $\mathbb{F}[G]$-modules over a field $\mathbb{F}$, and $G$ is a finite group.

Claim: Suppose there is a map $f: M \rightarrow N$ such that $f$ is a $\mathbb{F}$-vector space isomorphism, and $f$ is $G$-equivariant. Then $$H^*(G, M) \cong H^*(G, N)$$ as $\mathbb{F}$-vector space.

In other words, two group cohomology are isomorphic if they have isomorphic coefficients.

Is my statement above true? I feel like something is missing, but I have no clue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's your argument?  Probably something like use $f$ to get an equivalence between two resolutions.  Where does this fail for you?

Comment: homology is a functor, taking isomorphic objects to isomorphic objects

Comment: @fyx1123581347 Do you mean that the way is by treating group cohomology as a functor of two variables (G, M), where G is the same and map between M and N are isomorphic.